Reading the full comment addressed to me on a question that got deleted quickly afterwards
I commented on a question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4986265) over on Math.SE. When I returned a minute or two later, the question had been deleted, and I could see in my inbox that someone (probably the OP) had left a followup to me comment starting with "@Henriksupportsthecommunity ", i.e. addressing me, but the preview that was shown there (and also in my inbox) also has the first part of the message  and ends with ". Si...". Can I in any way get to read the whole comment?

I've had this happen on other sites, but luckily I can see deleted posts on math.se. They replied: "Henriksupportsthecommunity I was asking what the community prefers. I prefer the first way. Simple is better".

Thanks @JonathanZ, I actually thiough about adding to the question that I don't have enough reputation to see deleted questions.

There isn't such a way, but if you think the comment had something important, you can hop into the per-site chat, post the link to the comment, and ask for a screenshot. Usually high rep users are in chat, and if you ask nicely, can't see reason why they'll refuse.
